# Meaning of this #pragma notation

Tags: c++

What could be the meaning of this notation.

```
#pragma warning( disable : 4530 )
```

Comment: Looks like it is to disable compiler error 4530: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2axwkyt4.aspx

Comment: You should post whatever context this line came with.

Comment: Note that `#pragma` is the standard facility for nonstandard compiler extensions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite naturally, it disables warning number 4530.

Answer (score 3):

it instructs MS's compiler to ignore warning #4530

Answer (score 2):

Its does exactly what it says it does, it disables compiler warning number 4530. On a side note, this isn't a free ticket to just ignore warnings, it should only be used for special cases

Answer (score 1):

This line will disable all warnings with the code 4530. Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) article for more details.

Answer (score 1):

It means disable warning message numbered `4530`.

The general syntax of this pragma is:

```
#pragma warning( warning-specifier : warning-number-list [; warning-specifier : warning-number-list...] )
```

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

As everybody said `#pragma` is used to disable the warning coded `4530`..

But from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2axwkyt4.aspx),

> C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc

Also,

> When the /EHsc option has not been enabled, an object with automatic storage in the frame, between the function doing the throw and the function catching the throw, will not be destroyed.

To get *rid* of this,

> Compile the sample with **/EHsc** to resolve the warning.

It is unwise to disable **all** the warnings as they creep in. And in this case instead of *silencing* it, you can compile it with the **/EHsc** option...

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 1):

> 16.6/1- "A preprocessing directive of the form # pragma pp-tokensopt
>   new-line causes the implementation to
>   behave in an implementation-defined
>   manner. Any pragma that is not
>   recognized by the implementation is
>   ignored."

An implemention defined behavior is supposed to be documented by the vendor. So you need to look into the documentation.